# php login only works after refresh

Tags: javascript, php, sql, forms, authentication

I'm working with a simple login system with php/sql.
used it several weeks working on localhost, but now that the site is actually online, my login page doesn't work (only if i refresh the page)
working with session.
Are there any tips/things i can try to make it actually go to my index.php instead of manually refreshing the page? As i said it worked locally, nothing changed when going online.

[image]

LOGIN.JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
"use strict";
$("#submit").click(function () {

    var username = $("#myusername").val(), password = $("#mypassword").val();

    if ((username === "") || (password === "")) {
        $("#message").html("<div class=\"alert alert-danger alert-dismissable\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>Please enter a username and a password</div>");
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "checklogin.php",
            data: "myusername=" + username + "&mypassword=" + password,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (html) {
                //console.log(html.response + ' ' + html.username);
                if (html.response === 'true') {
                    windows.location.assign("http://kdlk.heijsgroep.nl/heijs/index.php");
                   window.location.reload(true);
                    return html.username;
                } else {
                    $("#message").html(html.response);
                }
            },
            error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#message").html("<p class='text-center'><img src='images/ajax-loader.gif'></p>");
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

});

main_login.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("location:../index.php");
    }
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <form class="form-signin" name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <input name="myusername" id="myusername" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus>
        <input name="mypassword" id="mypassword" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <!-- The checkbox remember me is not implemented yet...
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
        -->
        <button name="Submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>

        <div id="message"></div>
      </form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- The AJAX login script -->
    <script src="js/login.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

login header

```
<?php
//PUT THIS HEADER ON TOP OF EACH UNIQUE PAGE
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("location:login/main_login.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Can you provide some code ?

Comment: check the session exists or not in logi page .if session exists redirect it to index page otherwise login page .

Comment: change assign to href like this windows.location.href ="http://kdlk.heijsgroep.nl/heijs/index.php";

Comment: Still the same problem, not redirecting to index.php untill i refresh the page.. cleared browser cache/history/everything

Comment: Sessions don't exist on any page until a reload occurs. You're starting the session on a remote page with AJAX, so no reload occurs...hence no session to check here `if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {`